# Any suggestion for companies or service for global SMS API?

Tags: sms, asp.net-web-api

You might used whatsapp or LINE from iOS or Android smartphone.
You need to activate your account but input your phone number at the first time.

And the app will try to send a SMS message to your phone for authentication.
Do you have any suggestion how they achieve this?
As far as I think, there might be some SMS API Service companies to help on that.

If so, do anyone have some suggestions or list for those companies which provide integrated global SMS Service API (via Web API to trigger)
And also if I want to receive SMS message from users, is there any suggested company to help on receiving SMS?

Or is there any better way to achieve similar goals (Sending and Receiving SMS via Web API worldwide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that the company Twilio does it. Check this out http://www.twilio.com/api/sms

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is often called as two-factor authorization, mobile verification API, one time password API. We (and me, personally) implemented this as a part of our [SMS API](https://developer.wavecell.com).

As a first step, you must [generate the code](https://developer.wavecell.com/v1/api-documentation/verify-code-generation). And after the user received the message and entered it in your UI, you're [validating it](https://developer.wavecell.com/v1/api-documentation/verify-code-validation).